# getting search results of types "route" in google maps

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I'm using google maps API to geocode a list of addresses detailed to street level (street, city, country). 
One of the address I need to geocode is Niemcewicza, Warsaw, Poland the url I pass to curl is:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Niemcewicza+Warsaw+Poland

but this is however returning the element which is of type bus_station, not a route type. Probably because the full street name is Juliana Ursyna Niemcewicza. I tried to use components and limit search to components=route:Niemcewicza but this resulted in ZERO_RESULTS. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Niemcewicza+Warsaw+Poland&components=route:Niemcewicza

Is there a way to obtain geocoding result of type route for not complete street names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use city & country as address and the known part of the street-name as route-component.

At least for the given example it works for me:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Warsaw+Poland&components=route:Niemcewicza

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't thought of that